# Does Ubuntu 18.04 supports wireless multifunctional keybord such as Logitech k400?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, logitech, wireless-keyboards

I have Ubuntu 12.04 so far, but it has so many problems with wireless keyboards (2.4GHz) such as the "normal" keys do not work and special keys do or "normal" do and special do not. Yes, I tried 12.10 and I think the same. Guess I need to upgrade... So my question is:

Does new Ubuntu (like 18.04, or something like Mint) support keyboards with a touchpad, like Logitech k400 (using 2.4GHz connection)?  If Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't have this support, are there any other Debian distributions that do?

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu. You apear to have the wireless keyboard already, so my suggestion is to try running Ubuntu 18.04 off a USB drive or DVD using the Desktop iso image. From there you can test the keyboard and touchpad and decide for yourself. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of Ubuntu have better track/touchpad support.  As Ubuntu is available as 'LiveCD', you can try out a [newer version of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) without affecting your current system, and [test the functionality of your mouse, keyboard, and other devices before upgrading](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).  To be clear, you won't use the LiveCD to update, just to see what you can expect.

Once you see 18.04 (or whichever version) working, you can use [`do-dist-upgrade`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html.en) to upgrade your system.  Using this, and looking up information/issues for each upgrade, you will move from one release (ideally, LTS only) to the next, until you get to the latest version.  In your situation, you'll go from 12.04 to 14.04 to 16.04 and finally to 18.04.  It's always a good idea to see if Ubuntu has any notes for the specific jumps/upgrades.  Normally, there should be no concerns, but sometimes there are additional details or steps.

Have you looked into [Solaar](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/)?

> Solaar will detect all devices paired with your Unifying Receiver, and at the very least display some basic information about them.
>
> For some devices, extra settings (usually not available through the standard Linux system configuration) are supported. For a full list of supported devices and their features, see [devices](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/devices.html). I see k400 listed.

Note: I have a Logitech (Bluetooth) keyboard with a trackpad that has been working since (I believe) 16.04, and works in 18.04.  Please try 18.04 using 'LiveCD' and update your question with any specific issues you come across with your specific keyboard.

Comment: I am trying to use microsoft wirless usb keyboard with ubuntu 18.04.
When i connect usb and turn on the switch on the keyboard , it list on command `lsusb`. But keyboard is not working ? Could you help me ?